# Generate derived trait with same methods but without first parameter in each method in Scala

Tags: scala, code-generation

### Context

I have a defined a few "client" interfaces in my scala backend app and they roughly have this shape:

```
trait BackendClient {
  def foo: FooClient
}
trait FooClient {
  def doSomething(authToken: AuthNToken, request: MyBarRequest): Future[Unit]
  def getSomething(authToken: AuthNToken, id: MyId): Future[MyResource]
}
```

I want to keep the `authToken` in the method signature in the backend to remind implementations they should check auth for each method call.

In the frontend though, it becomes annoying to pass the same token everywhere, so ideally I'd want to have an "authenticated" client:

```
// Would like to auto-generate this given `FooClient`
trait AuthenticatedFooClient {
  def doSomething(request: MyBarRequest): Future[Unit]
  def getSomething(id: MyId): Future[MyResource]
}

// Auto-generating this too would be nice but not as important
class AuthenticatedFooClientImpl(authToken: AuthNToken, delegate: FooClient) extends AuthenticatedFooClient {
  override def doSomething(request: MyBarRequest): Future[Unit] = delegate.doSomething(authToken, request)
  override def getSomething(id: MyId): Future[MyResource] = delegate.getSoemthing(authToken, id)
}
```

This way I can have something like this in the frontend:

```
trait AuthenticatedBackendClient {
  def foo: AuthenticatedFooClient
}
class FrontendAuthServiceImpl(backendClient: BackendClient) extends FrontendAuthService {
  private val getTokenOrAuthenticate: Task[AuthNToken] = Task { ... }.memoizeOnSuccess

  val backendClient: Task[AuthenticatedBackendClient] = for {
    authToken <- getTokenOrAuthenticate
    authenticatedFoo = new AuthenticatedFooClientImpl(authToken, backendClient.foo)
  } yield new AuthenticatedBackendClient {
      override def foo: AuthenticatedFooClient = authenticatedFoo
    }
}
...
...
...
val someId: MyId = ...
val myResource: Task[MyResource] = for {
  backendClient <- frontendAuthService.backendClient
  myResource <- Task.fromFuture(backendClient.foo.getSomething(someId))
} yield myResource
```

### Problem

I would prefer not having to manually maintain 2 copies of my client traits, one with the auth token in the method, one without.

I'm pretty sure I can write my own annotation processor (I know that macros are probably more idiomatic in scala, but I've never really gotten around learning them) to generate the code I want, but this feels like something that should be solvable with existing libraries / tools.

Specifically, it feels like I should be able to generate a trait that is equal to another trait but drops the first arg of all of the other trait's methods.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a higher-kinded type parameter and parametrize the client depending on the situation:

```scala
trait GenFooClient[F[_]] {
  def doSomething(request: MyBarRequest): F[Future[Unit]]
  def getSomething(id: MyId): F[Future[MyResource]]
}

type Id[A] = A
type AuthenticatedFooClient = FooClient[Id]
type FromToken[A] = AuthNToken => A
type FooClient = GenFooClient[FromToken]

def authenticate(f: FooClient, token: AuthNToken): AuthenticatedFooClient =
  new GenFooClient[Id] {
    def doSomething(request: MyBarRequest): Future[Unit] =
      f.doSomething(request)(token)
    def getSomething(id: MyId): Future[MyResource] =
      f.getSomething(id)(token)
  }
```

It gets a little bit easier to write if you use the kind-projector plugin:

```scala
// no need for `FromToken` type alias
type FooClient = GenFooClient[AuthNToken => *]
```